# How to Stop Suspended Execution in observeEvent() Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

Im new to shiny R...Here is my code...

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
fluidPage(mainPanel(actionButton("run","RUN")))
```

server.R

```
function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$run,{
                print("Start")
                Sys.sleep(2)
                print("End")})
}
```

The problem is ...when i press run before console prints previous "end"....it starts executing observeEvent again as soon previous observeEvent ends...is there any way to stop pipelining of observeEvent queue?????

all i want is to stop user interactions on 'run' button while function is already in execution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of search i finally got solution ....which solved my purpose....

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),mainPanel(actionButton("run","RUN")))
```

server.R

```
function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$run,{
    shinyjs::disable("run")
                print("Start")
                Sys.sleep(2)
                print("End")
                shinyjs::enable("run")})
}
```